# PHP Derby Connection using the IJ tool?

Tags: php, sql, jdbc, derby, embedded-database

I'm writing a PHP program to read from a Derby database and was wondering if there was a way to connect to an embedded Derby Database using the ij tool.

The host machine is a Mac and I couldn't find a free/open source tool for the obdc driver, but I was able to use the ij tool to read into the db.

I was able to extract the the structure using dblook and parsing that information with :

```
 $cmd = $dblook." -d \"jdbc:derby:" .$db. "\" -t ".$table; 

 exec($cmd, $output);
 foreach ($output as $item){
    $arr = explode(' ',trim($item));
    if($arr[0]=="CREATE"){
      echo $item;
      break;
    }
 }
```

So would there be a way to something similar to connect using the ij tool? like:

```
 $cmd = $ijlocation." -d \"jdbc:derby:" .$db. "\" -t ".$table;
```

Or any other way for me to get an output of the table data that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can invoke 'ij' from your PHP program, you could give ij an argument which is the name of a file of commands to run: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/tools/ttoolsij98878.html

Then in that file, have two lines:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:$db';
select * from $table;
```